# Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing

I am facing a strange problem with my angularjs project.

I have a website like - www.server.com/pwm (home page). In the page there is an anchor tag with takes me to another page - www.server.com/publishers. When I load the home page and navigate to the publishers page by clicking the anchor tag, everything works fine. But when I directly type the url in the browser I get the below exceptions (eg. If I load the home page www.server.com/pwm and then type "/publishers" at the end of the url)

[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap"

The confusing part is that I have included the necessary libraries and it works fine when I navigate through the webpage. The problem occurs when I try to directly navigate to a child page. I am making use to ngRoute and templates to load the page

```
var pubsApp = angular.module('pubsApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

and my script files

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Is this a single page app? If so, what does your routing table look like?

Comment: im not familiar with angular for bootstrap, but dont you include both, angular and jquery as well as both of their respective bootstrap.js files? Id suppose to leave out at least `/Scripts/bootstrap.js`...

Comment: The `src` for ui-bootstrap's js files is relative so there really is no wonder why it doesn't work. Make them absolute like the rest?

Comment: you don't need ui-bootstrap.min.js and ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js. ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js contains all code and the templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your script tags are using absolute paths (they start with a /) except for the  angular-bootstrap tags; they use relative paths.  That means they are relative to wherever you are in the browser.

Your javascript files are all located at www.website.com/Scripts/... because all of your script tags except those two use absolute paths, they will *always* look for the script in the same place.  However, the two angulcar-bootstrap paths will look in different place depending on where you are in the browser.

The reason it works unless you go *directly* to the child page is because angular only loads javascript files on the initial page load and not on navigation.

So simply change your angular-bootstrap script tags to use absolute paths like the rest of your script tags.

Comment: This is really a good point. I will check making these changes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I also had same problem and I resolved it.
Detail is below.

Check your {{project_root}}/test/karma.conf.js

And be sure to bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js in it.
In your case, you should put Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js in it.

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess, it has nothing do with ui-bootstrap. This issue is related to angular routing. 
Please try this server.com/#/publishers  (When writing location at address-bar manually).

Comment: I don't think this answer helps